# Is there any solution for easy maintenance of Selenium automation scripts for testing Salesforce?

Tags: test-automation, selenium

Whenever there is salesforce upgrade, the `Xpaths` of lot of web elements get effected. This causes us to maintain them. Is there any better solution to this problem?

I have found a solution for input elements which are associated to an Id. here is the link:
https://www.parasoft.com/blog/tips-tricks-for-testing-salesforce-enterprise-apps-with-selenium/

But the above solution solves it for only input elements, is there any other solution for reducing the maintenance efforts for button and fields to read the data as well?

Comment: Use a paid for system like Virtuoso that provides "healing" of the detailed scripts by having you define the script processing using higher level abstractions. It isn't strictly maintaining Selenium though Virtuoso can generate and export Selenium scripts.

Comment: In case you are wondering, I mean https://www.virtuoso.qa/ - while the website doesn't have in-your-face info about using it with Salesforce, it does work with Salesforce. Here's a link to a [marketing video](https://www.virtuoso.qa/videos/salesforce-automation).

Comment: Please note that I am not affiliated with virtuoso and only use them as an example based on trialling their capabilities with Salesforce.

Comment: also - [Provar](https://www.provartesting.com/) as another vendor in this space that is specifically oriented at SFDC; I'm not affiliated with them

Answer (score -1):

[Edited as per David's comment] - You can use open source framework : http://testzeus.com/ to automate the UI tests for Salesforce. As the framework *dynamically generates xpaths* , therefore the maintenance costs are dramatically reduced.
On the other hand, Salesforce has a healthy community for Test Automation trailblazers here : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F93A000000DQPdSAO?tab=discussion&sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC

P.S. - I am affiliated with the TestZeus project.
P.P.S - With every quarterly release from Salesforce, UI scripts might be impacted, so the only other easier way of reducing maintenance effort would be to use a commercial solution such as Provar.

Comment: Robin, Salesforce Stack Exchange has a clear [promotion policy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), as well as guidelines on what a great answer looks like ([answer]). Please [edit] your post to comply with these guidelines, at minimum by disclosing your affiliation to this project.